# How to subset columns based on threshold values specified for a subset of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to subset columns of a big dataframe that adhere to this rule:

For *each* row (*except* row A) the value should be below 5.

Given the following example dataframe, I want the function to return a dataframe with **only** column c1 since all values in row B:E are below 5. I think the select_if function is probably the way to go, but I can't figure out how to exclude specific rows in that function.

```
Gene <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
c1 <- c(500, 1, 0, 3, 0)
c2 <- c(240, 235, 270, 100, 1)
c3 <- c(0, 3, 1000, 900, 2)
df1 <- data.frame(Gene, c1, c2, c3)
head(df1)

  Gene  c1  c2   c3
1    A 500 240    0
2    B   1 235    3
3    C   0 270 1000
4    D   3 100  900
5    E   0   1    2
```

Comment: `select` functions select columns.  `filter` functions select rows.  `select_if` and similar preedicate functions have been superseded by `across`.  `pmin` or `matrixStats::rowMins` will probably be helpful.

Comment: Yes, but by using the filter function to e.g. filter out row A, we lose that information in the resultant dataframe, which I still need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tidyverse solution is

```
df1 %>% 
  select(
    df1 %>% 
      filter(row_number() > 1) %>% 
      summarise(across(starts_with("c"), max)) %>% 
      pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
      filter(value < 5) %>% 
      pull(name)
  )
   c1
1 500
2   1
3   0
4   3
5   0
```

Explanation: the code inside the `select` calculates the maximum value for each column after ignoring the first row.  The result is then `pivot`ed into long format, creating default columns `name` and `value`.  This data frame is filtered to select only those columns where every value is less than five.  The `name` column is then `pull`ed and used as an argument to the outer `select`.

If you need other columns, just modify the `select`, for example,

```
df1 %>% 
  select(
    c("Gene", 
    df1 %>% 
      filter(row_number() > 1) %>% 
      summarise(across(starts_with("c"), max)) %>% 
      pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
      filter(value < 5) %>% 
      pull(name)
  )
)
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, thanks for the code and explaination.

Comment: You’re welcome! A follow-on discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72489003/how-to-select-columns-depending-on-multiple-conditions-in-dplyr?noredirect=1#comment128053462_72489003) arrived at an even more elegant and succinct solution.

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution is simple to code.

```r
i <- sapply(df1[-1], \(x) all(x[-1] < 5))
df1[c(TRUE, i)]
#>   Gene  c1
#> 1    A 500
#> 2    B   1
#> 3    C   0
#> 4    D   3
#> 5    E   0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To avoid reshaping or looping, use the `colSums`.

```
df1[c(1, which(colSums(df1[-1, -1] < 5) == 4) + 1)]
#   Gene  c1
# 1    A 500
# 2    B   1
# 3    C   0
# 4    D   3
# 5    E   0
```