# How to select columns depending on multiple conditions in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a solution in `dplyr` for the task of `select`ing columns of a dataframe based on multiple conditions. Say, we have this type of `df`:

```
X <- c("B", "C", "D", "E")
a1 <- c(1, 0, 3, 0)
a2 <- c(235, 270, 100, 1)
a3 <- c(3, 1000, 900, 2)
df1 <- data.frame(X, a1, a2, a3)
```

Let's further assume I want to select that column/those columns that are

- (i) numeric
- (ii) where all values are smaller than 5

That is, in this case, what we want to select is column `a1`. How can this be done in `dplyr`? My understanding is that in order to select a column in `dplyr` you use `select` and, if that selection is governed by conditions, also `where`. But how to combine two such `select(where...)` statements? This, for example, is not the right way to do it as it throws an error:

```
df1 %>%
  select(where(is.numeric) & where(~ all(.) < 5))
Error: `where()` must be used with functions that return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In all(.) : coercing argument of type 'character' to logical
```

Comment: Remarkably similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488041/how-to-subset-columns-based-on-threshold-values-specified-for-a-subset-of-rows?noredirect=1#comment128051819_72488041), posted earlier today.  I think the answers there will help you here.

Comment: No wonder it's similar as the present Q is a spin-off my attempts at finding a solution for that other Q. But no, there's no help there for this Q

Comment: Ah! OK.  I did wonder...  By the way, `df1 %>% select(where(\(.) is.numeric(.) & all(.) <5))` removes the error, but gives the wrong answer.  :=(  I was on the right line, but @benson23 beat me to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `where`, we need to supply functions that have logical results.

```
library(dplyr)

select(df1, \(x) all(x < 5))

# or this, which might be more semantically correct
select(df1, where(\(x) is.numeric(x) & all(x < 5)))

  a1
1  1
2  0
3  3
4  0
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c("B", "C", "D", "E"), a1 = c(1, 0, 3, 0), 
    a2 = c(235, 270, 100, 1), a3 = c(3, 1000, 900, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Is there a way to shorten the code a little by omitting `function(x)` and stuff? I've tried it myself but can't get it to work...

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Actually yes, we only need one `all` function without `where`

Comment: Why wont you use the formula notation for function? ie `where(~is.numeric(.) & all(. < 5))` ?

Comment: @onyambu Thank you for pointing this out! I didn't notice this until now, when I'm using `across`, I would use the `~` syntax, but in `where`, I somehow always use `function(x)`... It's only my personal habit and I guess I would use `~` in `where` in the future, thanks again!

Comment: you can use `~` in all tidyverse functions. You are not limited to only `across` and `where`

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr::mutate`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ if (all(.x < 5) & is.numeric(.x)) .x))

#>   a1
#> 1  1
#> 2  0
#> 3  3
#> 4  0
```

---

Or even more shortly:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ if (all(.x < 5)) .x))
```